# It is possible to create a new data frame on Pandas from a time series, with the daily diference?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Is there a way to create a new data frame from a time series with the daily diffence?

This means, suppose that on October 5 I had 5321 counts and on October 6 5331 counts. This represents the difference of 10; what I want is, for example, that my DataFrame shows 10 on October 6.

Here's my code of the raw dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mariorz/covid19-mx-time-series/master/data/covid19_confirmed_mx.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(url, index_col=0)

df = df.loc['Colima','18-03-2020':'06-10-2020']
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, format='%d-%m-%Y')

df
```

This is the raw outcome:

[image]

Thank you guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an inbuilt [diff](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html) function just for these kind of operations:

```
df['Diff'] = df.Colima.diff()
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use the [shift](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) method to access the preceding row's value to calculate the difference.

```
df['difference'] = df.Colima - df.Colima.shift(1)
```